# Can I save & store a user's submission in a way that proves that the data has not been altered, and that the timestamp is accurate?

Tags: security, validation, encryption, hashing, time-stamp

There are many situations where the validity of the timestamp attached to a certain post (submission of information) might be invaluable for the post owner's legal usage. I'm not looking for a service to achieve this, as requested [in this great question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195958/service-to-prove-authorship-with-trusted-timestamp), but rather a method for the achievement of such a service.

For the legal (in most any law system) authentication of text content and its submission time, the owner of the content would need to prove:

- that the timestamp itself has not been altered and was accurate to begin with.
- that the text content linked to the timestamp had not been altered

I'd like to know how to achieve this via programming (not a language-specific solution, but rather the methodology behind the solution).

---

1. **Can a timestamp be validated to being accurate to the time that the content was really submitted?**
2. **Can data be stored in a form that it can be read, but not written to, in a proven way?**

In other words, can I save & store a user's submission in a way that proves that the data has not been altered, and that the timestamp is accurate?

I can't think of any programming method that would make this possible, but I am not the most experienced programmer out there. Based on MidnightLightning's answer to the question I cited, this sort of thing is being done.

---

**Clarification:** I'm looking for a method (hashing, encryption, etc) that would allow an average guy like me to achieve the desired effect through programming.

I'm interested in this subject for the purpose of [Defensive Publication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_publication).

I'd like to learn a method that allows an every-day programmer to pick up his computer, write a program, pass information through it, and say:

> I created this text at this moment in time, and I can prove it.

This means the information should be protected from the programmer who writes the code as well. Perhaps a 3rd party API would be required. I'm ok with that.

Comment: To do it with any ability to prove it in a legal way, it likely needs to be cryptographically secure and that eliminates most of what even above average coders could do without very significant study.

Comment: For the answer to this question, I'm looking for an explanation the concept. `“If you can't explain it to a six year old, you don't understand it yourself.”` - Albert Einstein. I'm looking for the 7-year-old answer @MichaelT

Comment: Upload your documents to an online legal document signing service, and require only your own signature. Then sign it, with the current date. If their service is legal enough for the documents required in selling a house (!), it should be legal enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

You can take the content, append the textual representation of the timestamp), and then generate a cryptographically secure hash to the result which you store along with the data.  In the future, you can take the content that you've stored, the timestamp that you've stored, and repeat the process.  If the hash comes out the same, you can say with high confidence the content is unchanged.

Of course, this is only as secure as the hash algorithm that you choose.  Any hash will have some risk of collisions but a secure hash will make this risk incredibly small.  Ideally, if a hash produces a 32-bit number, you'd expect the odds of a collision to be 1/2^32.  A less secure hash will create the possibility that an attacker could change the timestamp and make a subtle change to the content that would produce the same hash when the two were concatenated together.  Even that, though, would generally require a pretty sophisticated attacker-- generating non-obvious hash collisions for even relatively weak hashes like MD4 (i.e. that don't require that the text is completely garbled) is rather challenging.

Assuming a perfect hash algorithm, any given string is converted deterministically into a hash but every hash is equally likely given the universe of inputs and which has no recoverable information about the original input string.  In a perfect world, if I have a 32-bit hash algorithm, knowing nothing about the string that I input, any of the 2^32 possible outputs would be equally likely.  Changing 1 character of the input string would also make any of the 2^32 possible outputs equally likely.  That makes it impractical, short of brute-force generating and trying 2^32 inputs, to find another input that produces a collision with any particular hash.  Of course, real hash algorithms likely aren't perfect (just like real encryption algorithms likely aren't perfect) so even the best algorithms probably aren't as tough to break as their raw bit-length would predict.  But they're likely good enough that no attacker is going to be able to produce a collision over the lifetime that you care about the information.

Comment: That's great to know. Could you perhaps (in a simple manner) explain why the hashing achieves this result? I think I know, but if you were to elaborate, I wouldn't have to guess.

Comment: @jt0dd - Added more information about what hashing accomplishes.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, you would use timestamping services for this sort of thing. A timestamp service is a well-known service that performs the following tasks:

1. You send a small bit of data to the service (such as a hash).
2. The service combines this data with the current timestamp.
3. The combined data is signed with the service's private key.
4. The service sends the combined data and signature back to the client.

This allows anybody to validate that the given hash was signed at the given time, by validating the signature using the service's public key.

In answer to your questions:

> Can a timestamp be validated to being accurate to the time that the content was really submitted?

Yes, if everybody trusts the timestamp service (the timestamp service can be neutral and can sign timestamp submitted by friends and enemies alike). Consider for example a timestamp service offered by a national government (if you only care about transactions within a particular country), or by an entity such as a Swiss bank.

> Can data be stored in a form that it can be read, but not written to, in a proven way?

Yes, because the signature of the timestamp service can be verified at any time using the service's public key.

NOTE: Both "Yes" above come with the usual caveats of properly implemented services. If the timestamp service is compromised in any way, signed timestamps may become suspect.

There are other solutions to this problem as well. The Wikipedia article on [Trusted timestamping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping) gives a good overview.

Comment: Good answer. Do you know of a few such services that provide APIs to automate the process?

Comment: @jt0dd: The EU maintains a [Trusted List of Certification Service Providers](http://ec.europa.eu/digital-agenda/en/eu-trusted-lists-certification-service-providers), which would be a good starting point.

Comment: I'm still interested in a method that is 100% in-house (no third party), but such a thing is probably not invented yet. For now, I'll have to accept a 3rd party API, I expect.

Comment: @jt0dd: Well, if you create your own timestamped data with *no* third party involvement, it's unlikely that anybody else would have a reason to believe you if the validity of your timestamp were called into question. However, distributed methods (such as storing a hash inside a cryptocurrency block) rely on distribution of the information but do not rely on a *single* (or *specific*) third party.

Comment: It would require the private key to be inaccessible by the programmer but still able to sign the data. Possible? I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what you want with pure digital information theory.  However, there is a way to use a trusted assistant to help you.  The classic version of this involves posting information in a classified column on a particular day in a particular newspaper.  It is exceedingly difficult to forge such a post after the fact, so it is generally treated as trustworthy.

Now the real challenge is deciding what information to post.  Obviously posting all of your timestamped data to the classifieds would get old after a while.  However, posting a hash of all of the timestamped data you collected (including hashing the timestamps themselves), and posting that to the newspaper daily would be reasonable.  Then, if you have to prove the timestamp in a court of law, you merely reveal all timestamps in that block.  Anyone verifying you simply needs to hash the data, then go look in the newspaper for that hash.

This of course, only provides one bound - you can't have possibly generated the timestamped data after the newspaper received the hash, but it could have been generated any time before hand and delayed until you "needed it."  For many legal situations, just an upper bound is sufficient.  For others, more careful bounds are needed.  A common solution, which happens to be used by bitcoin, is to chain the data.  Store your timestamped data, and hash it.  You then create a chain of hashes combining this hash of timestamped data with the last entry in the chain.  This does not prevent you from falsifying a time, but it does make it dramatically more difficult because now you have to falsify every entry that follows the injected data.

There are hundreds of variants of these verification schemes using tools like this, but they all fall into two steps:

- Create a "proof" document which is small enough to be easy to manage (such as a hash)
- Provide this "proof" document to a trusted third party who can reasonably vouch that it received the proof

Remember that legal requirements are usually to some level of doubt.  This gives flexibility.  For example, if you need to prove a log message's time to a minute, you might use a 2 step process.  Daily, you post the hash of your entire log to a newspaper or other trusted entity.  Every minute, you publish the hash of the logs on a public website. If nobody downloads those minute logs, they may try to discredit them, but they cannot discredit the newspaper data, and the mere fact that you constantly publish verifiable data may be sufficient to assuage doubt by demonstrating that you had a desire to be held to a strong standard.

Answer (score 0):

I worked at a shop that stored images of legal documents in a database. In order to achieve security, all user documents were stored this way:

- take a hashcode of the document
- encrypt the document & store it
- encrypt the hashcode & store it
- take a hashcode of the encrypted document & store it
- take a hashcode of the encrypted hashcode & store it

Now, it's still possible for someone who has all the encryption keys to change everything, but if any one of those get out of sync, they could detect the tampering.

(Full disclosure: to this day, I'm unsure if that process was brilliant or just a convincing way to sound brilliant without actually accomplishing anything.)

I'm not certain that's a sufficient, or even good, solution, but essentially the answer to your question boils down to hashcodes, encryption, and saving different pieces in different places.

In your case, it might be sufficient to save the text and the hash of the text in separate data stores. On any retrieval, check to make sure they still match. However, someone with root access could still defeat that if they knew what they needed to do.

Comment: The goal is to prove the authenticity within reason, to the extend generally required by a system of law. I think the only question that I have about your answer is "Wouldn't someone else need to hold the keys?"

Comment: Because if I possess the keys, it seems that it's my word alone authenticating the documents. +1 for secure storage though.

Comment: Generally, if you keep the keys in *another* secure data store, then that's good enough. But, like I say, someone with root access can unravel the whole thing -- because the application itself needs to be able to read and write those documents. So that opens up the broader problem of securing your servers, network, and databases. But that's kind of a well-known problem, and boils down to protecting PII (Personally Identifiable Information) and PCI (basically credit card information).

Comment: The issue becomes "now how can I protect this system from myself?" (Protection from root access is important in order to ensure that the system is self sustaining). Otherwise, "an average guy like me" can't do it. I'd need to involve a third party.